# If (something got printed) x=false, how to do this in R?

Tags: r

So I am using a function in R that uses compiled fortran code. While using this function, `lsoda`, in package `deSolve`. I get messages printed to the screen like

```
DLSODA-  At current T (=R1), MXSTEP (=I1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching TOUT     
In above message, I = 
[1] 5000
In above message, R = 
[1] 21.31629
```

The problem is that the above is not a "warning" or an "error"; the `is.null(warnings())` evaluates to TRUE after I see this message. If it were a warning I could just write `x = is.null(warnings())` and that would do the trick. I could use tryCatch for errors, but what about messages that are neither errors or warnings?

The reason I ask, is that this function is called in a while loop, inside a for loop. I want the while loop to break if this message gets printed, and then for the outer for loop to move onto the next iteration. Normally you'd use tryCatch to do something like this but because there is no error, I have no idea how to do this

Comment: You can redirect the output and then check if it contains something like that. Please, provide reproducible example

Comment: @JulianUrbano hmmm, not sure what you mean by that, the reason I want to know this is that I want an inner while loop to break if this message gets printed, and then for the outer while loop to move onto the next iteration. Normally you'd use tryCatch to do something like this but because there is no error, I have no idea how to do this

Comment: Please give us a reproducible example so we can show you how to redirect

Comment: Maybe you can use "capture.output" and match the msg y ou are looking for

Comment: @JuliánUrbano my example is long and ugly and slow and I can't think of a toy problem that would contain the essance of the problem. Perhaps if you included a link to what you mean by redirect, googling "redirect in R" didn't produce what I think you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output and then check whether `lsoda` printed something:

```
out <- capture.output(lsoda(...))
if(length(grep("In above message", out))!=0) {
   # error
}
```

We basically check whether any of the lines printed by `lsoda` contains the string `In above message`. If you need to use the result from `lsoda`, you can also run like this:

```
out <- capture.output(result <- lsoda(...))
```

As suggested, you can also use `grepl`:

```
if(any(grepl("In above message", out))) {
   # error
}
```

Comment: or `grepl` for a shortcut

Comment: capture.output is exactly what I was looking for! thanks so much. Will accept answer as soon as I verify this works with my code (It looks like it should).